# Spring data JPA and transaction management

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

In my spring service I call two spring data repository methods

```
@Service
public class ClientService {
    public void updateClientByIdAndKey(final Integer id, final String key) {
        final Client client = clientRepository.findByIdAndKey(id, key);
        // .. Update client details
        client.save(client);
   }
}
```

Now my query is related to the transaction management. As far as I understand and have seen code, spring repositories have transactions enabled using @Transactional for its methods. For select operations it has readonly=true.

My understanding about transaction is that when select operation is executed then a transaction is created and then for the save operation another transaction is created, since for select operation transaction is readOnly=true.

I wanted both read and write operations to be executed in a single transaction. If my understanding above is correct then having **@Transactional** over service method **updateClientByIdAndKey** will run both in one transaction which is my intention or will spring execute both operation in one transaction?

Please let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: As said in the doc : _By default, CRUD methods on repository instances are transactional._ . Source : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ReadOnly property of @Transactional is defaulted to false. By simply annotating the method with Transactional both the read/select operation and the update operation will happen in a single transaction. Should you change the property to true I am guessing you will not have two transactions occurring, but instead an exception will be raised when the update is attempted.

EDIT:
If the method is not annotated with Transactional both operations will not execute in a single transaction. In fact, depending on how you how configured your ORM, an exception may be thrown when executing the update as the connection will have been closed following the select.

Comment: Thank you for your input @Dean. But  query is will spring data internally execute both select and update operations in one transaction, if I don't annotate service method with @Transactional?

Comment: Are you using Hibernate?

Comment: If you don't annotate service method with `@Transactional` annotation spring will execute both queries without any transaction. So data will be persisted on `save` method call.

Answer (score 1):

When you add `@Transactional` annotation to your `updateClientByIdAndKey` method, spring will create only one read-write transaction (unless you put additional `@Transactional` annotation on your `findByIdAndKey/save` method with `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW` or other type of [propagation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html). When you add `readOnly = true` to `@Transactional` spring will set `flushMode` on the Hibernate session will be set to `NEVER`. That mean you can't perform any create, update, delete operations.

Answer (score 1):

method **findByIdAndKey** don't need to do COMMIT (store changes to database) and should be annotated as

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
```

method **updateClientByIdAndKey** should use

```
@Transactional
```

in **updateClientByIdAndKey** just one read-write Transaction is used unless your nested method **findByIdAndKey** defines a

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

In this case you are explicitly creating a new (readonly) Transaction that doesn't make sense.